# How to create user group in gpedit.msc on Windows 7 Ultimate

Tags: windows-7, group-policy, gpedit

I have created four user accounts on my laptop and want to divide them into two groups. Each group will be given limited access to an application. For example group 1 can access only the desktop and cannot open "My computer" (C, D, E drive). If I set any policy, it is applied to all user accounts. I need to create a separate user group so that I can set the policy only for that group. How can I do it?

Answer (score 2):

- [How to Create and Delete a User Group in Windows 7 and Vista](http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/202251-user-group-create-new-delete.html)
- [How to Apply Local Group Policies to a Specific User or Group in
  Vista and Windows 7](http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/151415-group-policy-apply-specific-user-group.html)